# How to trigger OneSignal API call with Swift Button

Tags: swift, onesignal

Can y'all help me with a project? I am pretty new to API's, and I'm wondering what the best way to call OneSignal's create new message API is, using a clickable UI button in Xcode and Swift. I was able to get the API working and sending a notification using PHP on a web server, but I don't have enough knowledge to convert this to a simple button in Xcode.

The API docs list a whole bunch of different examples in different codes, but I didn't even know which one to start with for Swift. Basically, I'm just needing a button that sends the API request to send out a OneSignal push notification.

API Docs: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

Comment: have a lokk at very famous library in iOS development for making network calls: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to send a request on the `UIButton` tap event, you could use as follows:

```swift
    @IBOutlet weak var btnTap: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnTap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func onTap(_ sender: AnyObject) -> Void {

        let url = URL(string: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        //add the parameters here as needed
        let parameters = ["username": "foo", "password": "123456"]

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            //the service response is here
            print(response)
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

But when working with notifications, the best way to handle is server side. You can use your .php file as an endpoint and just send the post request there.

I strongly recommend reading [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) for better understanding.

Comment: That gets me a ways! I setup onesignals provided PHP code on my web server, and used your code to call my php file. I'm not sure how to get the parameters to work though.

Comment: It is a key-value dictionary. You would send the info your PHP file needs, get them on the server side via $_POST and use on the onsignal connection